# Get java variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, extjs

I am working on extjs3.2 Grid.I am using spring and hibernate.I am using below link

http://loianegroner.com/2010/09/extjs-spring-mvc-3-and-hibernate-3-5-crud-datagrid-example/

I am adding my data using

```
modelMap.put("val", '12345');
```

Now my question is how will i get val variable in my javascript file.I am already using

```
modelmap.put('data',city)
```

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: try in javascript like: `var val = ${val};` Note: on the jsp not external js file.

Comment: @Rembo are u sure it working??

Answer (score 1):

You could try to identify the element using jQuery class selector and calling *innerHTML* and assign it to a variable:

```
var val = $("class-selector").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to fetch it in a JS file. Since the model map will only be available when the server compiles and prints out the JSP page, the variables are available only in a JSP file and not in a JS file.

If you have a JS file and want to use it, you'll need to store the value in a variable in a JSP file and then access the variable in the JS file.

So, JSP code is:

```
var myVariable = ${val};
```

then put the JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js">
```

Inside myfile.js, you can use the variable:

```
Ext.request({
  url : 'myUrl/'+myVariable,
  success:..
});
```